# iOS app wont run: unable to dequeue a cell with identifier Cell

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, swift2

My app currently has a `TableView` with customized cells. I've searched already for the problem but the solutions I saw online had something to do with the `IBOutlet` connections, but my UI element's connections are fine. How do I solve this?

XCode: 7.0.1
Language: Swift

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   '`NSInternalInconsistencyException`', reason: 'unable to dequeue a cell
>   with identifier Cell - must register a nib or a class for the
>   identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'

Comment: Try to add an exception breakpoint to get more info about crash reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT:** I added your log error on your question. Based on this you should check if you have set the correct cell identifier on your table view in your storyboard.

[image]

Your code, in your `cellForRowAtIndexPAth` delegate, is trying to dequeue a table view cell named `Cell` but it did not find any cell named like this.

Comment: the error i got was: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier Cell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'

Answer (score 0):

You have not registered the name of the cell in your identity inspector of xcode. Please check it!
[image: This could be of some help for your reference.]

Comment: it has already been set earlier. :( what could be wrong? :(